# Nesting Ruby on Rails HAML Checkbox in Label Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the following code which doesn't work:

```
= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => "well" }) do |f|

= f.label :email
= f.email_field :email

= f.label :password
= f.password_field :password
- if devise_mapping.rememberable?
 %p
  = f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" 
    = f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox"

  %div= f.submit "Einloggen"
= render :partial => "devise/shared/links"
```

It only works in that way, but I need it in one line and not in wto:

```
%p
  = f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" 
  = f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox"
```

Please help! I'm really desprate right now. I just want the checkbox nested in the label for the bootsrap form. I searched google and stackoverflow but found nothing

UPDATE:

I solved it now like this:

```
- if devise_mapping.rememberable?
%p
  %label.checkbox{ :for => "remember_me" }
    = f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox"
    Remember
```

Comment: Have you tried http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about :

```
%p
  = f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox" do
    = f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "checkbox"
```

Comment: For what I can tell, when you want to nest something in HAML, either it's under regular markup, and nothing to do (except indent), either it's under ruby code, and then you have to indent and supply it as a block (given the ruby method accepts it)

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
%p #{f.label :remember_me, :class => :checkbox} : #{f.check_box :remember_me, :class => :checkbox}
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. I get the " and eveything split up in two lines :( But thanks

Comment: I just check my project and I have without doublequote. And it works.